# Is it possible to change google doc (table) using google API?

Tags: google-docs-api

Following the API's description :

> "The Google Documents List API allows developers to create, retrieve, update, and delete Google Docs"

What if I need to write something in a table using an external application?

Answer (score 0):

This is totally and completely possible. For example, I am using python to create and update Google Doc Spreadsheets based on what the user does. There are multiple languages for you to choose from and all are fairly well documented.